# Lua error in package.lua at line 80: module 'Module:No globals' not found

Tags: php, mediawiki, wiki, lua

I have installed MediaWiki and am now finally getting to `import/export` templates from wikipedia to make it shinny like a door knob. However I am running into this road block: `Lua error in package.lua at line 80: module 'Module:No globals' not found.`

Steps to reproduce:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export
- `Add pages from category: > Template:Infobox`
- Download xml
- go to someurl.com/index.php?title=Special:Import
- upload xml with `Interwiki prefix` set to `Wikipedia`
- Navigate to one of the imported pages: `someurl.com/index.php/Template:Infobox`

[image: Script error: No such module "Infobox". Script error: No such module "documentation".]

## LocalSettings.php

```
wfLoadExtension( 'AntiSpoof' );
wfLoadExtension( 'AbuseFilter' );
#wfLoadExtension( 'MobileFrontend' );
wfLoadExtension( 'VisualEditor' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Echo' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Thanks' );
wfLoadExtension( 'WikiLove' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Scribunto' );
wfLoadExtension( 'SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi' );
wfLoadExtension( 'WikiEditor' );
wfLoadExtension( 'CodeEditor' );

# Vairables for Lau to work properly
$wgDefaultUserOptions['usebetatoolbar'] = 1;
$wgScribuntoDefaultEngine = 'luastandalone';
$wgScribuntoUseGeSHi = true;
$wgScribuntoUseCodeEditor = true;
```

How can I get these simple templates from wikipedia work?

Comment: The warning says, there is no `Module:Infobox` and no `Module:documentation` in your wiki. Can you verify that? What happens when you open [`Module:Infobox`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module:Infobox) in your Wiki? Did you tick `Include templates` on the export page?
`Lua error in package.lua at line 80: module 'Module:No globals' not found.` - Where exactly is that message displayed? Was [`Module:No globals`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module:No_globals) imported to your Wiki?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:Export
2. Export `Module:No_globals` and `Module:Message_box/configuration`
3. Import the XML at `/Special:Import` of your MediaWiki installation
4. Enter interwiki prefix as `Mediawiki`

If the template still report any `Module Not found` error, you can repeat the above step for the reported module

Comment: Though this operation completed successfully, it didn't affect the error for me